# Reusing Layout in Android (<include>)

Tags: android, android-layout

I am fresher in android.In my project I have one layout common for all activities. And I am trying to reuse my layout in Android.Following is my code

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


    EditText emailEdit, passwordEdit;
    Button loginButton;

    TitleBarLayout titlebarLayout;
    String r;
    String rr;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);

        emailEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        passwordEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

        loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        //titlebarLayout=(TitleBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.titlebar);
        titlebarLayout=new TitleBarLayout(MainActivity.this);
        titlebarLayout.setLeftButtonText("Refresh");
        titlebarLayout.setRightButtonText("Logout");
        titlebarLayout.setTitle("iProtect");

        OnClickListener listener=new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(v.getId()==R.id.left_button)
                {}
                else if(v.getId()==R.id.right_button)
                {}

            }
        };
        titlebarLayout.setLeftButtonOnClickListener(listener);
        titlebarLayout.setRightButtonOnClickListener(listener);
    }
}
```

login_activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/layout_bg_color">

    <include layout="@layout/titlebar_layout" 
        android:id="@+id/titlebar"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@layout/titlebar_layout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dip"
        android:background="@drawable/emailedit"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:maxEms="20"
        android:paddingLeft="70dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="user@gmail.com" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etEmail"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
        android:background="@drawable/passwordedit"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:maxEms="20"
        android:paddingLeft="70dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="123456" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/login_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/login_button_height"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
        android:text="Login" 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivFooter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="360dip"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:src="@drawable/footer" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

titleBarlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/titlebar_height"
    android:background="@color/title_bg_color"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/left_button"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/titlebar_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/titlebar_button_height"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_textview"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/right_button"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/titlebar_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/titlebar_button_height" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And TitleBarLayout.java

```
public class TitleBarLayout extends LinearLayout {

    private WeakReference<Activity> activityRef;
    //Button leftButton, rightButton;
    private View contentView;
    Button leftButton,rightButton;
    TextView titletext;

    public TitleBarLayout(Activity a) {
        super(a);
        Log.i("TitleBar Layout", "Inside constructor");
        activityRef = new WeakReference<Activity>(a);
        inflateViewsFromXml();
        setListenersOnViews();
        setValuesOnViews();
    }

    private void setValuesOnViews() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    private void setListenersOnViews() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }

    private void inflateViewsFromXml() {
        Activity a = activityRef.get();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) a.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.titlebar_layout, null);
    }

    public void setLeftButtonText(int resID) {

    }

    public void setLeftButtonText(String resID) {


        Log.v("Button", "Button Text="+resID);
        if (contentView != null) {
            leftButton = (Button)contentView.findViewById(R.id.left_button);
            Log.i("ERROR", "Inside setLeftButtonText");
            leftButton.setText(""+resID);
            leftButton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }

    public void setLeftButtonOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener) {
        leftButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }

    public void setRightButtonText(int resID) {

    }

    public void setRightButtonText(String resID) {

        Log.v("Button", "Button Text="+resID);
        if (contentView != null) {
            Log.i("ERROR", "Inside setRightButtonText");
            rightButton = (Button)contentView.findViewById(R.id.right_button);
            rightButton.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            rightButton.setText(""+resID);

        }
    }

    public void setRightButtonOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener) {

        rightButton.setOnClickListener(listener);

    }

    public void setTitle(int resID) {

    }

    public void setTitle(String resID) {

        //@string/app_name
        Log.v("TextView", "Text="+resID);
        if (contentView == null) {
            Log.i("ERROR", "Inside setTitle");
            titletext = (TextView)contentView.findViewById(R.id.title_textview);
            titletext.setText(""+resID);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to add text on buttons at runtime.But I cant get it? I can see text on Logcat but not on button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inflating the layout into the variable view 'contentView'.
But because your class is the view that you are inflating in the xml file. You should inflate is as following:

```
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.titlebar_layout, this);
```

Then the layout will be visible on the screen.

This way the inflate will add the inflated view to the `LinearLayout` where your class is extending from.

Comment: what then if I do not extend with Linearlayout?

Comment: Than you cannot use it inside an xml file (You can if you override onMeasure, onDraw and onLayout). Did you try what i said before?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't correct. Android already is inflating the title bar, so you shouldn't have to inflate it again. Instead, you can just use findViewById to get the title bar's XML information. I think you can use the @+id to do this with that you supplied to the  tag

Update: edited for correctness since I misread the code

Comment: titlebarLayout=new TitleBarLayout(MainActivity.this);
If This is not correct then how can i get the instance of TitlebarLayout class.         Also when we inflate we get error in (Button)findViewById(R.id.right_button)
instead we have to write (Button)contentView.findViewById(R.id.left_button);

Comment: I see what you mean. However, I just edited the answer to be correct.